# How show value to element in DOM (javascript or jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

I need to know how to refer to an element in DOM (javascript or jquery).

In this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ejn7DmCnKMYWx0QVIwODRMMU0/view?usp=sharing

How I can refer to the item: thb -> 0 -> childNodes -> 3 -> innerText ???

Comment: Post relevant code in the question itself

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

In addition, you should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scope in which you have set a breakpoint, I see that `thb` is a variable.

In this case you can refer to the inner text through :

```
var myText = thb[0].childNodes[3].innerText;
```

`myText` is now the innerText